# Does snapshot change tracking break DDD principles?

Tags: c#, mvc, domain-driven-design, entity-framework

I'm building a website with MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6, implementing the Unit of Work & Repository patterns, and - for flexibility and performance - would like to utilize Entity Framework's snapshot change tracking rather than proxy change tracking. The drawback of this feature is that navigation property fix-up is not done until `DetectChanges` is called by `DbContext`.

Adding an item to a collection...

```
order.LineItems.Add(orderLineItem);
```

The inverse association will not be updated until `DetectChanges` is called...

```
lineItemOrder = orderLineItem.Order; // lineItemOrder == null
dbcontext.DetectChanges();
lineItemOrder = orderLineItem.Order; // lineItemOrder == order
```

This navigation property fix-up behavior seems too specific to Entity Framework for the level of abstraction I'd like to see. Does this behavior break principles of Domain Driven Design, or can `DetectChanges` be considered a business transaction?

Comment: Wouldn't a better question be "does snapshot change tracking fulfill my business needs?"  Or maybe "Can I get snapshot tracking and still be faithful to DDD principles?  Seems odd that a development methodology would prevent certain functionality from occurring.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suppose "Can I get snapshot tracking and still be faithful to DDD principles?" is closest to what I'm asking. It's the property fix-up that makes me wonder if DDD principles are violated. Should the state of associations within the domain model be affected by the unit of work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly not a business transaction, as one would expect lineItemOrder.Order to be readily populated without needing to call separate method,

With this approach not only it would be hard to debug, the domain model is not working as one expect it to work.

When designing a domain model one should try to keep domain model clean from supporting frameworks such as persistence.

personally I would not use

```
order.LineItems.Add(orderLineItem);
```

when designing a domain model, instead I would use

```
order.AddLineItem(orderLineItem);
```

and make the `order.LineItems` readonly

If it is possible to encapuslate the `dbcontext.DetectChanges();`inside the method `AddLineItem` it would be a better domain model even though it's not the optimal design,

Comment: After thinking about it, I agree. I think I might resort to implementing the property fix-up myself.